# How to Show dialogs (reply/forward/etc) programmatically from within outlook 2010 addin

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a mail item that is picked from one of the folders of outlook. I'd like to open, say outlook native Reply dialog for this mail item. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more detail? Are you developing some addin for outlook that will pick some email and open the native reply dialog for you? Are you using VSTO for developing the add-in?

Comment: @Tariqulazam Yes I'm using VSTO and like to open the native reply dialog for a specific mail item my addin is processing at that time. This dialog will be shown to user. It's just like clicking on reply/reply all toolbar buttons when viewing the email.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have figured out the answer myself (so fast!)

After some googling, I landed on this page [Outlook Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268893.aspx), Stumble upon the following point

> Use the GetInspector method of a specific item, such as a MailItem or ppointmentItem, to retrieve the Inspector that is associated with it.

Note from that page only

> The Inspector object represents a window that displays a single item such as an e-mail message, task, or appointment

At this point I remembered that MailItem has methods for forward/reply; however, those return respective MailItem objects. I then remembered that I also saw there a Display method within the class that shows an associated inspector ... browsing through to the definition of Display, it was revealed that it "displays" a new inspector for that object. Wow!

So here's the code for those who are keen to know and has to read all through my perhaps boring tale of deduction:

mailItem.Reply().Display();

It's that simple! What a shame! :-)